# How to integrate razorpay in Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, razorpay

I am using Vue js Cdn and not using node. so I want to know how can I integrate Razorpay in Vue as inside Vue template script tags are not allowed. Can anyone help me with that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to implement the manual checkout as given on the Razorpay docs. Read [this](https://docs.razorpay.com/docs/checkout-form) for reference. You can include the script tag in index.html.

```
<button id="rzp-button1">Pay</button>
<script src="https://checkout.razorpay.com/v1/checkout.js"></script>
<script>
var options = {
    "key": "YOUR_KEY_ID",
    "amount": "2000", // 2000 paise = INR 20
    "name": "Merchant Name",
    "description": "Purchase Description",
    "image": "/your_logo.png",
    "handler": function (response){
        alert(response.razorpay_payment_id);
    },
    "prefill": {
        "name": "Gaurav Kumar",
        "email": "test@test.com"
    },
    "notes": {
        "address": "Hello World"
    },
    "theme": {
        "color": "#F37254"
    }
};
var rzp1 = new Razorpay(options);

document.getElementById('rzp-button1').onclick = function(e){
    rzp1.open();
    e.preventDefault();
}
</script>
```

Comment: Can you specify error handler like how to get error when payment fails or manual cancel?

Comment: Razorpay handles the errors for you I think. Manual cancel shouldn't be a problem either.

Your handler function would be called after the payment is successful. But it's been 2 years since I worked with it so you should test it for yourself. Try logging the response object to console and check if there is any abnormality in different cases.

Comment: In test environment it is working fine and gives normal success response which consist of 3 ids, but in production what scenario can come that is what i am not sure of, because in production we cant know what response we got in success handler apart from normal success response.

Answer (score 0):

This works

Add a ref element

```
<div ref="rzpform"></div>
```

Then append the script tag on `mounted` event programmatically.

```
var form = document.createElement("form");
var rzpScript = document.createElement("script");
rzpScript['src']="https://cdn.razorpay.com/static/widget/subscription-button.js";
rzpScript.setAttribute('data-subscription_button_id', "pl_IXOuwF4EldEpc5");
rzpScript.setAttribute('async', true);
form.appendChild(rzpScript);
this.$refs.rzpform.appendChild(form);
```